# could not delete file neither via java nor manually

Tags: java, file, io, delete-file

I have the following situation, within a servlet a create a file and then have to delete it. 
When executing the file, I figured out that the file is still in the server, so I tried to remove it manually, I can't, I get the following message :

> this file is opened by another program : javaw.exe

Here is my code :

```
public class GenerateFile extends Action { 
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("ok");
        String fileName = request.getParameter("fileName");
        Integer nbrParam = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("nbrParam"));
        String[] valueParam = new String[nbrParam+1];
        for(int i =1;i<=nbrParam;i++)
        {  System.out.println(request.getParameter("param"+i));
            valueParam[i]=request.getParameter("param"+i);
        }
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\free\\Desktop\\myworkspace\\gestionRH\\WebRoot\\fiches\\"+fileName+".doc");
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(in);
        HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);
        Range r = doc.getRange();
        for(int i=1;i<=nbrParam;i++)
        {   System.out.println("<param"+i+">");
            System.out.println(valueParam[i]);
            r.replaceText("<param"+i+">", valueParam[i]);
        }
        File  file = new File("C:\\Users\\free\\Desktop\\myworkspace\\gestionRH\\WebRoot\\fiches\\temp");
        File temp = File.createTempFile("monfile",".doc",file);
        String tempName =temp.getName();
        doc.write( new FileOutputStream(temp));
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType("application/rtf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=Decision");
        FileInputStream in1 = new FileInputStream(temp);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int length;

        while ((length = in1.read(buffer)) > 0){
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        in1.close();
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("C:\\Users\\free\\Desktop\\myworkspace\\gestionRH\\WebRoot\\fiches\\temp\\"+tempName);
        File f = new File("C:\\Users\\free\\Desktop\\myworkspace\\gestionRH\\WebRoot\\fiches\\temp\\"+tempName);
        f.delete();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: For Pete's sake, fix your code format... (if you have already formatted code, just copy&paste it in here, select it and hit `Ctrl+k`

Comment: You can't delete a file which is being used/open under Windows. You have to wait until the file is no longer used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are creating a `new FileOutputStream(tempName)` to write on that file, but never closing that outputstream (or another outputstream linked to it).

Do this:

```
FileOutputStream fos = newFileOutputStream(tempName);
// use it
fos.close(); // CLOSE IT!!

// then you can delete the file
```

**Simplify**

Maybe you could do the work another way, without temp files...

by example: `doc.write(new FileOutputStream(tempName))` could be replaced by:

```
doc.write(response.getOutputStream());
```

This way doc sends its bytes directly to where you need them, not to a temp file eliminating the need for it.

The idea behind input/output streams is composing them. Input/OutputStream are the abstract base classes. And there are a lot of implementations:

- based on memory: ByteArrayInput/OutputStream
- based on files: FileInputOutputStream
- compressing/decompressing to another outputstream: GZipInputOutputStream
- and so on

The beauty of it is applying decorator pattern to add functionality. By example:

```
new GZipOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream());

// creates an outputstreams that compress data received and send it to the other stream
// the BAOS then writes the received bytes to memory


new GZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream());
// it's the same but sending compressed bytes to a file.
```

Comment: thank you for this good, well explained and generous answer !

Comment: concerning simplification id do it like this : OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
  doc.write(out); out.flush

Comment: i get some stange charachters on my page instead of save dialog

Comment: @fatiDev: tell me what change have you done? just closing the out to the file? I'd try the `doc.write(response.getOutputStream())` approach (to eliminate chances) but don't write until all response headers are setted :)

Comment: That's because when you write the body of the response headers part is automatically "commited" (finished and sent to the user). So do headers first and then write the doc.

Comment: yeah , that's the problem , when i wrote the headers first it works nickel

Answer (score 4):

You should close all the file-reading object instances. Besides, if you can delete the file manually, you should close java and then delete it, javaw is the process that launches java outside the console.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like, you are not closing the file(out), thus it remains with the thread of this action, which is restricting it to get deleted.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should try [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to find out what process exactly holds the file opened

Answer (score 1):

For IO features, I would to suggest to use some kind of jar already provided by community.
For example, common-io.x-x.jar, spring-core.jar

```
    Eg, org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
        FileUtils.copyDirectory(from, to);
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(childDir);
        FileUtils.forceDelete(springConfigDir);
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, data);

        org.springframework.util.FileSystemUtils;
        FileSystemUtils.copyRecursively(from, to);
        FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(dir);
```

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you open a file handler, you should close it. In a Java application that you want to run for a long period of time, you are strongly recommended to close all unused file handlers soon after you finish working with them.

Examples of common file handlers are `FileOutputStream` and `FileInputstream`. Here is a good example of how you open and close the `FileOutputStream`

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(tempName);
    // do something
} catch (IOException ex) {
    // deal with exceptions
} finally {
    // close if fos is not null
    if (fos != null) {
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

You should never do this:

```
doc.write( new FileOutputStream(temp));
```

because you can never close the file handler if it has no refernce to it.